# Struct declaration in Swift Package results in compilation error when used

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

I have this compilation error on the line declaring ingredient in RecipesVC.swift when I declare the IngredientStruct as part of a swift package.  However, I do not see this when I declare the same struct in the project.  Here is the code snippet:

RecipeStruct.swift   // this is in the swift package Recipes

```
import Foundation
public struct IngredientStruct: Encodable, Decodable, Identifiable {
    public var id :                          String
    public var recipeID :                    String
    public var ingredientName :              String
    public var ingredientReplacement :       String
    public var measurementType :             String
    public var measurementQuantity :         Int
    public var storage :                     String
}
```

RecipesVC.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import Recipes  // from Recipes swift package
struct RecipesVC: View {
    var ingredient: IngredientStruct = IngredientStruct(id: "", recipeID: "", ingredientName: "", ingredientReplacement: "", measurementType: "", measurementQuantity: 0, storage: "")  // "Extra arguments at positions #1, #2, #3, #4, #5, #6, #7 in call\n  Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call \n Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call \n Insert 'from: <#Decoder#>, ‘”

    var body: View {
    …
    }
}
```

Now, if I declare the same IngredientStruct in a local project file, it compiles fine. I am not sure as to what I need to do in Swift package to make this compile. Any pointers?

@workingdog - my bad.. error in cut&paste in a hurry - lost 2 lines in the struct as well as the second error for the same line.  I updated the names to lowercase as well. However, I still see the same errors.

Here is the Package.swift file:

```
import PackageDescription
let package = Package(
    name: "Recipes",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v15), .macOS(.v12)],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "Recipes",
            targets: ["Recipes"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [ ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "Recipes",
            dependencies: []),
        .testTarget(
            name: "RecipesTests",
            dependencies: ["Recipes"]),
    ]
)
```

Comment: I'm not surprised it does not compile, there are no `IngredientReplecemnt` and `Storage` in the `IngredientStruct`. Also I suggest using lowercase names.

Comment: ok, you may have another `IngredientStruct` somewhere in your code, try this: `var ingredient: Recipes.IngredientStruct = Recipes.IngredientStruct(id: "", ...)`

Comment: @workingdog: There is no other IngredientStruct in the code.  adding "Recipes." prefix  does not change the error.

Comment: if you have `RecipesVC` in the swift package `Recipes`, you don't need to have`import Recipes`.

Comment: @workingdog:  True!  However, I am planning to share Recipes package between multiple projects - that is why I am trying to provide the models in the package and views in the apps.

Comment: I think this is an issue with swift packaging. Not quite sure as what this is.

Comment: Updated the issue with the Package.swift file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a struct is being made public, it must be initialized appropriately. In the example above, the init() looks like this:

```
public struct IngredientStruct: Encodable, Decodable, Identifiable {
    public var id :                          String
    public var recipeID :                    String
    public var ingredientName :              String
    public var ingredientReplacement :       String
    public var measurementType :             String
    public var measurementQuantity :         Int
    public var storage :                     String

    public init(id: String, recipeID: String, ingredientName: String, ingredientReplacement: String, measurementType: String, measurementQuantity: Int, storage: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.recipeID = recipeID
        self.ingredientName = ingredientName
        self.ingredientReplacement = ingredientReplacement
        self.measurementType = measurementType
        self.measurementQuantity = measurementQuantity
        self.storage = storage
    }
}
```